# Unable to catch the error when sending email

Tags: transactions

I have a simple transaction, where I send an email to some users, and then save the email data into a table.

My current query looks like this.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION T1
BEGIN TRY
EXEC [MSDB].dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='Email Test',
@recipients='test@gmail.com',
@subject='Testing auto notification sql jobs. Please ignore',
@body_format = 'Text',
@body = 'Hello',
@query = 'some random query'

IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION T1
END
ELSE
BEGIN

Update TBL_Email_Log set EmailSent = 'Y'
COMMIT TRANSACTION T1
END
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH 

PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION T1
END CATCH

GO
```

Somehow when I check the email log table, the value is set to y. The transaction does not seem to rollback, for some reason.

I am sure, I am missing something simple here.

Edit:

Turns out the code does not work if the query fails. It takes care of other error. But, if the query fails for any reason, @@Error returns zero, and no exception occurs either.

Comment: When it is able to run successfully, why will it rollback?

Comment: second part is running successfully. the first part is failing, i made sure of it. even then, it continues to second part. if the email failed to send, it should stop, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, solved it. Turns out, query errors are not returned as @@Error, but instead as a return value. So, declared a variable, saved return code to that variable, and then used that variable along with @@Error.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION T1
BEGIN TRY
DECLARE @ReturnCode int
EXEC @ReturnCode = [MSDB].dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='Email Test',
...

IF @@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0
BEGIN
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION T1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
Update TBL_Email_Log set EmailSent = 'Y'
COMMIT TRANSACTION T1
END
END TRY
...
```